# The intersection of the null space of 2 matricies, is the null space of the subtraction of the 2 matricies

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

I'm thinking about the intersection of the null space of matricies $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$.

The null space of each matrix is:

$\mathcal{A}x = 0$

$\mathcal{B}y = 0$

Id like to find the intersection of these two null spaces. Hence I want to find the subspace of all vectors $z$, s.t. {$z \in \mathcal{R} | Az = 0\mbox{ and }Bz = 0$}.

Now I already know that if I define a new matrix $C = [A;B]$ (col stacked) then the $z = \{Cz=0|z\in\mathcal{R}\}$ is in the null space intersection.

However,

$\mathcal{A}z = 0$

$\mathcal{B}z = 0$

Hence, $\mathcal{A}z = \mathcal{B}z$, and hence $(\mathcal{A}-\mathcal{B})z = 0$. Therefore the intersection of the two null spaces is really the null space of the subtraction of the two matricies.

Is this true?

Comment: Think what will happen if $A = B$. In that case, the null space of $A - B$ is whole domain, while that of $A$ might not be. In particular, if $A = B = I$, then the null space of $I$ is $\left\lbrace \textbf{0} \right\rbrace$, while that of $A - B = 0$ is whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the domain.

Comment: Your comment makes sense. But what if A != B?